# Active android Select query

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

```
new Select("id")
.From(customer)
.where("lastName=?","John")
.execute();
```

> Error

```
 E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
```

> Main query (select id from customer where lastName="John";)

Comment: Could you please be more specific on your issues? Add some code maybe then we will able to help you the best as we can

Comment: Show the code where the exception actually happens (i.e., where you try to read from the cursor).

Comment: `Failed to read row 0, column -1` means no such column exist in your query result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<Customer> results = new Select().from(Customer.class).where("lastName=?","John").execute();

if(results.size() > 0) {
    long id = results.get(0).getId(); 
}
```